# Application for Prayer Time need help in programming language and calculation

Tags: java, android, math, geography, astronomy

I want to make an Android application for an university project which calculates prayer times.

The first line in the code is:

```
d = jd - 2451545.0;  // jd is the given Julian date
```

How can I obtain a Julian date?

Also, in the code `RA = arctan2(cos(e)* sin(L), cos(L))/ 15;`, how does the comma work? How can I execute this statement mathematically and/or programmatically?

Comment: before asking local imam Question 2 should be solved because I could not calculate values at all

Comment: @GabeSechan "ask your local imam" -- ha ha ha. Cut it out. If you don't know how to obtain a Julian date, just stay out of it.

Comment: @RobertDodier He edited the question.  Originally he had a link to a page noting the times of prayer each day and adking if it was accurate.  That part was removed.  Check the edit history on the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891905/12478830

Answer (score 1):

On your 3rd question:

`RA` is the result of a function called `arctan2` divided by `15`([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)), that takes 2 values seperated by a comma. Those two values are results of a calculation itself, `cos` respektivly `sin` of the values `e` or `L`. Because `sin` and `cos` only take 1 parameter, there is no comma, because no values have to be seperated.

Answer (score 0):

Julian date 0.0 is 01/1/4713 BC, so the number of days since that date till 01/01/2000 is = (4712+2000)*365.25-13=2,451,545 days.
13 days are subtracted because there was a correction on Georgian calendar that happened on 3/9/1752 which was made 13/9/1752 which makes a 11 days lost, plus there where two leap years in 1800 & 1900 without 29th FEBRUARY, so there is a 13 days difference to be accounted for in the formula above.